# How to compile Allegro 5 program with GCC using only C programming language

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, allegro5

stackoverflow, et. al.,

I just installed Allegro 5 on my Ubuntu machine and I see some source code for this game development tool, but I do not see specific instructions for how to compile it.

For C programs I use gcc on the terminal.

My questions are:

- From what directory do I compile allegro5 programs?
- What compiler options are necessary? (the normal *gcc someCProgram.c -o MyProgram* doesnt work)

Thank-you for reading. I have read two c books so I am not a complete noob, but I have the struggles...

All the best,

user2085446

Comment: Which bit of the [super detailed installation instructions for installing on an Ubuntu system, found on the allegro homepage](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Ubuntu_and_Allegro_5) do you not understand?

Comment: Wow! Thank-you for the reply. These detailed instructions are what made it possible for me to install allegro5, over allegro4. However, there is only a single compilation guide and it is for C++, using g++. By the way, I already have allegro5 installed, do you think that this is not the case? I need help compiling some 'hello-world' type of program please.

Comment: Okay, I may have been a little harsh with you. However, on the page I link you to there *is* a small section on compiling programs that use allegro, with an idea of how to construct the compiler options.

Comment: ...also the compilation instructions [on the page](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Ubuntu_and_Allegro_5) you mention do not explain what directory i should be in...

Comment: @us2012 - no worries, thank-you for replying at all. :D see my latest concerns above please.

Comment: I receive this error when compiling `error while loading shared libraries: liballegro.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: That probably means you didn't install allegro correctly.

Comment: Does the library exist in /usr/local/lib? Did you run `sudo ldconfig`?

Comment: `g++ [source file(s)] -o [output] `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0``. should the --libs option refer to where i installed allegro on my hard-drive or where allegro installed certain files somewhere on my machine, as in the usr/lib type of system directories ?

Comment: @Matthew it exists as a link or something, yes. The file properties are this: `link to shared library (application/x-sharedlib)`

Comment: @us2012 all of the example programs work in the examples folder based off of the `build` directory though

Comment: @user The `libs` option should simply say `allegro-5.0`, nothing else! That's the magic of `pkg-config`.

Comment: @Matthew I did not run sudo ldconfig - not sure what this does :/

Comment: @Matthew what directory do I run `sudo ldconfig` in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's put this into an answer:

If your program just consists of a single `.c` file, you can run `gcc` from the path the file is in. However, in general there's nothing wrong with invoking `gcc` from anywhere else as long as you get the paths right.

For linking with external libraries, you need `-lmylibrary` options in the compiler command, e.g. `-lfreetype` for the freetype library and so on.

Now, this can get a bit complicated when your libraries depend on other libraries etc. That's what the `pkg-config` tool is for.

When you look at the allegro wiki page, you will see the following sample command:

```
gcc [source file(s)] -o [output] `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0`
```

The `pkg-config` bit will resolve the relevant `-l` options for you.

Comment: Well I did get it to compile thanks to this help, but when I run it I still see the error.

Comment: @user Because you still need to run `sudo ldconfig`, see Matthew's comments above.

Comment: I ran it from the build directory i made based on the wiki instructions for initial installation... now it compiles and runs the c code without error. Thank-you for your help with this stackoverflow! :D :) : ) ^o^